# cast variable to enum after static cast

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Is it possible to cast a static_cast variable by reference into a function without having to declare an enum.

```
bool GetTest(enumTests &e_Test)
{
 //do something with test
}

enum enumTests
{
Test1 = 1,
Test2,
};

/* The below does NOT compile*/
int i = 1;
GetTest(static_cast<enumTests>(i));

/* The below compiles*/
enumTests e_Test = static_cast<enumTests>(i);
GetTest(e_Test);
```

Error

> 20:34: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type
>   'enumTests&' from an rvalue of type 'enumTests'

Comment: Temporaries can only be bound to `const` references.

Comment: It sounds quite sketchy to me to modify an int through an enum reference.

Comment: You can do `reinterpret_cast<enumTests &>(i)` or `(enumTests &)i`, though formally both are undefined behaviour. It may be well-defined if you specify the enum base type: `enum enumTests : int {...};`, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the latter is still not well-defined; the strict aliasing rule does not have an exception for aliasing an enum as its underlying type.  (Perhaps it should)

Comment: @OP do you intend for the function to be able to change `i` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
enumTests e_Test = static_cast<enumTests>(i);
GetTest(e_Test);
i = static_cast<int>(e_Test);
```

is the correct way.

Following would compile, but unfortunately, broke strict aliasing rule and so is UB:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(i), std::underlying_type_t<enumTests>>::value);
GetTest(reinterpret_cast<enumTests&>(i)); // Compile but is UB
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to bind a rvalue value to a non-const reference. So you need the extra variable pass it as a lvalue. 
Please see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category to understand what are lvalues and rvalues.

But it's not required to static_cast explicitly as shown.

```
#include <iostream>

enum enumTests
{
    Test1 = 1,
    Test2,
};

bool GetTest(enumTests &e_Test)
{
    e_Test = Test2;
    return false;
 //do something with test
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    auto ie = enumTests(i);
    GetTest(ie);

    std::cout << ie;
    i = ie;
    std::cout << i;
}
```